# Page deleted from Wiki. Recycle bin has been disabled

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, wiki

We have a Sharepoint WSS wiki site from which one of the users accidentally deleted the page. The recycle bin is empty as it has been disabled. I understand the WIKI maintains the older versions of the pages as well. Is there a way to restore the older version of the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a chance the page might be in the site collection recycle bin, available from Site Settings at the site collection root. (There are two levels of recycle bin, one site and one site collection.)

Otherwise unfortunately the page is not retrievable, unless you have a backup. If you need help with restoring from backup, please ask over at http://serverfault.com.